# Auto generate hash value for default column value in Snowflake table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am trying to create a table in Snowflake that automatically generate HASH value whenever I insert a record.  Similar to using function `UUID_STRING()`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test (
 id VARCHAR(16777216) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT UUID_STRING(),
 hash_id NUMBER NOT NULL DEFAULT HASH(id),
 name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
```

When I try to insert a record, it complains `hash_id` is null error and is not auto generating a hash value whereas `id` is working.

```
insert into test (name) values ('test');
```

Comment: This is working for me as you have it in the two code blocks. What is the exact error message?

Comment: Is kind of weird, it is now working for me after I `drop table test` and recreate again.  Thanks for verifying this @GregPavlik

Answer (score 0):

Answering here for closure: The code in the question works as intended.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE test (
 id VARCHAR(16777216) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT UUID_STRING(),
 hash_id NUMBER NOT NULL DEFAULT HASH(id),
 name  VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

insert into test (name) values ('test');

select *
from test;
```

[image]